# Find the duplicate in my list, and use it later in the code

Tags: python, pyautogui

Hi i am trying to write a code that checks for duplicates in my list. i want to use this duplicate later in the program (its for a puzzle, the one there is two of is the right answer to the puzzle).
I want the "duplicate" to be stored in "i" - that way i can do something like
if i = RGB_orange - do this or that. just an example

I have tried alot of diffrent things. this is the closest i got. Any help is appreciated.
BTW - the contents of that list is diffrent RGB values. coordiantes is another list, its where my program gets its RGB values.

```
    for x in coordinates:
            rgbvalue = Tappair.getpixel(x)

#            rgblist = [(94, 197, 189), ## just an example
#                   (127, 176, 254),
#                   (233, 131, 78),
#                   (239, 106, 253),
#                   (233, 131, 78),
#                   (225, 81, 99),
#                   (126, 230, 129),
#                   (139, 33, 200)]

            rgblist = []


            rgblist.append(rgbvalue)
            print(rgblist)
            for i in rgblist:
                if rgblist.count(i) == 2:
                    print(i)
                    print("Counted")
                    print(rgblist)
                    break
```

EDIT: this works:

```
def tap_the_pair():
if pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('TapPair.png', confidence=0.9, region=(689, 250, 640, 1000)) != None:
    Tappair = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(734, 429, 540, 540))
    Tappair.save(r"C:\Users\Andreas\Desktop\pythonProject\WholeTapPair.png")
    print("tap pair game found")

    rgblist = []

   # rgblist.append(rgbvalue)

    rgb_dict = {}

    for x in coordinates:
        rgbvalue = Tappair.getpixel(x)
        if rgbvalue in rgb_dict:
            print(rgbvalue)
            return rgbvalue
        else:
            rgb_dict[rgbvalue] = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution provided in the question also works, but it has a time complexity of O(n^2). A better approach with better time complexity can be to use dictionaries:

```
rgb_dict = {}

for rgb in rgblist:
    if rgb in rgb_dict:
        print(rgb)
        break
    else:
        rgb_dict[rgb] = True
```

After the loop ends, `rgb` will contain the duplicate. This solution has a time complexity of O(n).

Edit: try this code specific to your example. It can be done using a single for loop

```
rgb_dict = {}

for x in coordinates:
    rgbvalue = Tappair.getpixel(x)
    if rgbvalue in rgb_dict:
        print(rgbvalue)
        return rgbvalue
    else:
         rgb_dict[rgbvalue] = True
```

Comment: Im sorry but i cant get your solution to work? i will edit.

Comment: The second for loop is supposed to be executed after the `rgblist` is fully populated. Currently, your second for loop is inside the first for loop. The second for loop should execute after the first for loop is finished and rgblist is populated.

Comment: You are right - unfortunatly its still not giving me anything- i edited again

Comment: Your rgb_dict = {} is still defined in the first for loop. Define it outside the first for loop, and before the 2nd for loop.

Comment: I put it outside now- the program just doesnt return anything

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: I treid to run that - but get an error: return outside function (no matter where i place it)

Comment: Can you please share the complete function? There might be an indentation issue.

Comment: The error that you shared "return outside function" indicates that you are writing the return statement outside the function. Make sure it is indented properly, and falls inside the function. Plus, I have edited my answer to better suit to your question. It can be done using one for loop.

Comment: I understand - but no matter where is set the return it is marked with red and gives me that error

Comment: If i just delete the return, my code runs and prints the rgb value

Comment: I can better tell if I have the entire function header+body in which you are returning the rgb value.

Comment: Posted on bastebin

Comment: Plus, I have further edited the answer to include the return statement inside the loop, immediately after printing the duplicate value. I have replaced the break statement with the return statement. Please have a look.

Comment: i dont understand why - but its still not accepting it - even with your code.

Comment: Its because i am not within a function it seems

Comment: It works now that i made it inside a function

Comment: I saw the code in bastebin. It seems the code where you are returning the rgb value is not being executed inside any function, rather it is executed in the main file. Using the return statement only makes sense if you're using it inside a function. Try encapsulating your code in a function and call that function from main. By the way, your original question is answered since now you can access the duplicate rgb value.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the duplicates in your list with:

```
import collections

rgblist = [(94, 197, 189), (127, 176, 254), (233, 131, 78), (239, 106, 253), (233, 131, 78), (225, 81, 99), (126, 230, 129), (139, 33, 200)]

duplicates = [item for item, count in collections.Counter(rgblist).items() if count > 1]

print(duplicates)

for i in duplicates:
    # Do something with each duplicate
```

Output:

```
[(233, 131, 78)]
```

Comment: Thank you - i will ook at it